# Getting duplicate entry error after adding branch.io to my android project

Tags: java, android, twitter-fabric, branch.io, crashlytics-android

Everything was working fine, but after adding this to my android project error building apk started.Here is the error and dependency

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/crashlytics/android/answers/shim/R.class

```
 compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}
```

tried excluding it also but error persists.
Here is my full gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven"}
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    resConfigs "en_US", "hi_IN"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;

}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.9'
compile 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If i add the exclude statement to branch and digits then while entering the app it crashes,if added exclude to crashlytics the error persists.But without adding branch everything works perfect no error during apk build too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was struggling with this all day today as well. What ended up fixing it for me was rolling back branch to 2.5.9. There obviously seems to be something wrong with the new 2.6.0 release.

Another note for branch I don't have the transitive aar include so it's just

```
compile ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.5.9') {
    exclude module: 'answers-shim';
}
```

Comment: Hey Jarrod, your suggested solution works like charm man.Cheers:-)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the the issue  when removed `transitive = true` from the dependency
`compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.0@aar') {

    exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}`

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use the latest version of branch.io, you have to add the following lines in your proguard file.

```
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.**
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.appindexing.**
-dontwarn com.android.installreferrer.api.**
```

With this change `exclude module: answers-shim` is not required in the gradle file.